# Is it possible in python to specify that a generic type has some attributes and methods

Tags: python-3.x, types, mypy

In python I would like to create a function that would accept a generic parameter and that would return a value of the same type and I would like to somehow specify that the generic has some attributes and methods. I thought that binding a `TypeVar` to a `Protocol` would do the job, but I was terribly wrong

Just to give an example of such a function, let's say the function sorts the input array of some objects and returns sorted array of those objects. The only restriction on the array's elements is that they have to implement `__lt__`

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List, Protocol, TypeVar

class ComparableProto(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other: ComparableProto) -> bool: ...

Comparable = TypeVar("Comparable", bound=ComparableProto)

def sort(arr: List[Comparable]) -> List[Comparable]: ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sort([1, 2, 3])  # mypy will say: Value of type variable "Comparable" of "sortarr" cannot be "int"  [type-var]
```

I understand that the above example can't work, because `Comparable` type must be subtype of `ComparableProto` and just because some type implements `__lt__` doesn't make it subtype of `ComparableProto`.

I noticed that `typing` module implements several generic protocol types named `Supports*`, but they differ from what I want

Is there some way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost fine. There's nothing wrong with `TypeVar` bound to `Protocol`, you use it exactly as expected. The problem is in protocol definition: `int` is not compatible with `ComparableProto`, because it has `def __lt__(self, __other: int) -> bool`. Notice that `int` is comparable only with another `int`, while your protocol expects wider type, `ComparableProto`. You can verify that with a simpler program:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Protocol

class ComparableProto(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other: ComparableProto) -> bool: ...

x: ComparableProto = 1
```

`mypy` will explain, what's happening, with notes:

```
main.py:7: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "ComparableProto")
main.py:7: note: Following member(s) of "int" have conflicts:
main.py:7: note:     Expected:
main.py:7: note:         def __lt__(self, ComparableProto) -> bool
main.py:7: note:     Got:
main.py:7: note:         def __lt__(self, int) -> bool
```

I suggest you to play a little with this code in [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a622138b87534b3bfcdab68def2f1824) to understand this not very obvious part better.

Now things are clear. If you define your protocol comparable only (read: at least) with same type, error will go away:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List, Protocol, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T')

class ComparableProto(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self: _T, __other: _T) -> bool: ...  # Only same type allowed

Comparable = TypeVar("Comparable", bound=ComparableProto)

def sort(arr: List[Comparable]) -> List[Comparable]:
    return arr

sort([1, 2, 3])
```

Dunder name in protocols is used to explicitly say that name of argument is not important (so calling `obj.__lt__(other=something)` will be disallowed for protocol, but may be allowed for any subclass that has this argument named `other`). It's obviously the case for `__lt__`, because it is intended for use in operator form.

> I understand that the above example can't work, because `Comparable` type must be subtype of `ComparableProto` and just because some type implements `__lt__` doesn't make it subtype of `ComparableProto`.

Your understanding is wrong, every class that implements `__lt__` with proper signature **is** subtype of `ComparableProto` (and "subclass" term is not so important for protocols). Protocols are used to represent structural subtyping, so another class doesn't need to inherit from protocol to be compatible with it. For instance, `Sized` from `typing` (or from `collections.abc` if you're modern enough and use python 3.9+) is a protocol that defines `__len__(self) -> int`. Any class that implements `__len__`, that returns `int`, is compatible with (read: subtype of) `Sized` despite not inheriting from it. See [PEP544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#subtyping-relationships-with-other-types) for more formal rules (note that "subtype" term is used instead of "subclass" to avoid misunderstanding).

Comment: wow, @STerliakov, you solved my problem as well, really knowledgeable. thx.