# SQLAlchemy: using Mapped with protocols

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, protocols, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to define helper functions typed with protocols that will later be used on SQLAlchemy 2.0 mapped classes.

In my case, I'd need a specific mapped attribute of my SQLAlchemy class (ie a column) to be represented as a protocol itself. However, from looking at its source code I've found that `Mapped` is invariant - hence, if I understand correctly, the error below.

Any idea if there's a better way I could type-hint my classes / functions to make it work?

```py
from typing import Protocol
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped


# Protocols

class BarProtocol(Protocol):
    bar: Mapped[int]

class FooProtocol(Protocol):
    @property
    def bar(self) -> Mapped[BarProtocol]:
        ...

def f(foo: FooProtocol) -> BarProtocol:
    return foo.bar


# Implementations

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Bar(Base):
    bar: Mapped[int]

class Foo(Base):
    bar: Mapped[Bar]


f(Foo())  # Doesn't type-check
```

Mypy output:

```
error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "Foo"; expected "FooProtocol"  [arg-type]
note: Following member(s) of "Foo" have conflicts:
note:     bar: expected "Mapped[BarProtocol]", got "Mapped[Bar]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: first thought is maybe you are better off using ABC instead of Protocol... I suspect the generic type param will have to be a concrete type

Comment: ...I may be wrong about that though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100529/is-it-possible-in-python-to-specify-that-a-generic-type-has-some-attributes-and

Comment: Your protocol should be generic, like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=3888ad9150e51c218848de0bb8502938) (doesn't typecheck in playground without `sqlalchemy` installed, of course, but passes locally)

Comment: @STerliakov Yeah but then you end up having to provide a type parameter to every function using your protocols... And in a real-life case, a SQLAlchemy table will likely have many columns and relationships, each requiring its own type parameter - pretty uneasy to use. But thanks for looking into this! I ended up posting a [PR](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/pull/10289) to `sqlalchemy`, will see how it goes!

Comment: No, you won't have to provide type parameter - it'll be inferred from `__init__` arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mapped` has been made covariant in 2.0.21 (see [release notes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/changelog_20.html#change-4912ee2ba5731476579dbb664755253a)).